# Set GridSplitter position by program

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, grid, gridsplitter

How can I set the position of a grid splitter by program? I checked the monitoring tools in VB.NET during the runtime - but the only value that contained the information was private.

Answer (score 0):

use Grid method :

```
Grid.SetRow(yourgridsplitter,value) / Grid.SetColumn(yourgridsplitter,value)
```

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer. Sadly it didn't solve my problem in the first try. Yes the GridSplitter moved, but without the connected UI Elements, and now it moves no more. And I can't control the way it moves. No mater which numbers I put it's alawys at the same place. I looked the command up in the MSDN but it only says that it's a helpersub for xaml.